# Delphi: executing SQL queries on MemTable or other type of Dataset

Tags: sqlite, delphi, dataset, in-memory-database

I am using Firedac to create SQL Lite connection on a local .db file. I am using:

- TFDConnection: to create the connection object
- TFDQuery: to execute my SQLite queries.

What I want is copy all data or tables from my SQLite database file on memory and then execute SQL queries on it.

I've read that I can use mMemTable or other datasets but all information regarding this is more confusing than helping me out.

I want to achieve this because I have to run "heavy" queries (thousands of queries inside a for-loop) but without sacrificing so much speed and resources. Currently I have 5 query.open("SELECT * ....") inside a very big loop, making my code very slow. I suppose this derives from many query.open() stuff.

If I have a copy of my SQLite data on memory and then run queries on that dataset, it would increase my code speed drastically.

I have implemented this on another part of my code, where I used limited amount of data taken from SQLite file inside sorted lists, and then I iterated over my lists. Performance increased over 300% after replacing query.open() inside that big loop.

I cannot use the same method as mentioned above, because I want to run SQL queries from my "SQL in Memory" to fetch specific data with complex criteria.

So anyone can help me out with the above issue? Maybe a small and "clear" tutorial regarding this?

---

It seems that my question is still not answered. I will try to be more specific with another example of code in order to understand the situation. I am still trying to achieve what I was telling above. I want to copy data from my SQLite database on memory, DISCONNECT and then run SQLite queries on in memory database. It is supposed to work with TFDQuery, TFDLocalSQL, TFDConnection.

I am creating and fetching data from SQL file using "conn" connection and "query". Then I activate

```
try
   // connection with local SQL file to fetch data from
   query.Connection := conn;
   query.Open('SELECT * FROM CAMPAIGNS');
   query.FetchAll();
   // I've put SQL text because FDQuery1 must me active and SQL text must be 
   // included
   FDQuery1.SQL.Text:='SELECT 1';
   FDQuery1.Active:= true;
   // the following line of code, is supposed to copy data and structure
   FDQuery1.CloneCursor(query,true,true);
finally
   conn.Close();
   query.Free();
   conn.Close();
end;
// it seems from showmessage that records exist inside TFDQuery
showmessage(FDQuery1.RecordCount.ToString);
// when I execute the following query, it tells that such table does not 
// exist
FDQuery1.Open('SELECT * FROM CAMPAIGNS');
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Unfortunately it is not a site for providing tutorials.

Comment: Try to speed up queries by adding indexes to your SQLite database. Also, if you have a lot of loops with queries inside, you should check whether you can improve your algorithm by either replacing the outer loops logic with SQL logic or by once loading specific limited information from the database into hashtables or dicitonaries before.

Comment: I have made optimizations and replaced loop logic with SQL logic as far as it goes but I still meed more speed. I am using data to write on StringTable. Also I cannot use bindings (I am not very familiar with bindings and DataAware controls) for this kind of table because I use data in a very “custom” way fetching data from different tables and making many calculations before writing on the cells.

Comment: NineBerry, I ve read over 3,000 posts in stack overflow for a wide range of programming concepts and issues. I am not asking for an answer with a tutorial, but the way I can implement it. If someone has a solution posted somewhere else (maybe on another site) I would appreciate it. I just added this because maybe someone has already the answer but feels bored to write it down again here.

Comment: I don't think your comments are actually clarifying your problem, at least for me.  Where is your data actually persisted and retrieved from, Sqlite tables in a local file-system database or a proper RDMS on a server?

Comment: As mentioned on my question (in the beggining) I am using a local SQLite file. I want to fetch all data inside a dataset and then run SQL queries on that dataset. I want this “offline mode” in order not to read from the file directly, thus reducing execution time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A case of the blind leading the blind, I'm still trying to figure this out myself,
but I think you need to use a TFDLocalSQL as conduit between your TFDMemTable and TFDQuery. For more info, try http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Local_SQL_(FireDAC)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried loading the data from your tables by using the `data` property?

`FDQuery1.Open;
FDQuery1.FetchAll;
FDMemTable1.Data := FDQuery1.Data;`

Comment: How can I run SQL queries in MemTable? Even if I have data copied on a dataset, what I want next is to run queries on it (offline mode).

Comment: Use the TfdLocalSQL connect to create a local "db server" that can serve your memory table as dataset to a TfdQuery

Comment: If I just load data  database structure will not be copied and then when you try to execute any query, it will result in error "... such table does not exists".